# What is another way to crawl the web besides following links?

Tags: web, web-crawler

What is another way to crawl the web besides following hyperlinks?

Comment: It's incredibly unclear what exactly you're asking. There is no central, universal index of all requestable URLs, so crawling around and collecting each new URL that you find is as close as it gets. You can sprinkle in some "smartness" by trying to predict URLs (if `http://foo/1` is valid and `http://foo/3` is valid, then maybe try `http://foo/2` as well), but nothing that fundamentally separates you from the idea of collecting URLs from web content and using them to find more URLs.

Comment: Most sites today only have outgoing links to their social media nowadays. What I'm asking is is there another way to crawl the web?

Comment: If most sites only link to social media, how do you recon search engines find the other stuff? What kind of "other way" do you imagine? Your question is very open-ended.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How?

Answer (score 1):

Most major sites use [Sitemaps](https://www.sitemaps.org/). This gives your crawler a fast way of discovering URLs and can be used with or instead of following outlinks.

The [crawler commons](https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons) project provides a Sitemap parser in Java.

Comment: But then again a sitemap is just a URL that can be crawled with some other URLs that can be crawled in the content (yes, with some metadata, but fundamentally it's not different from crawling `http://www.example.com/` and finding links to the subsections).